# Stub a function which is inside the function to be tested

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a function let's say A whose output and functionality I have to test, A calls another function B which takes a lot of time to compute the output. So I am trying to use stubs to mimic all the values that B returns.

```
def A
  #do something
  output = B
  #do something with output
end
```

Now the test files

```
describe "check what A returns" do
   ClassName.stub(:B) do
     [0, 1]
   end
   test_values  = TestClass.A(input parameters)
   #checks on test values
end
```

My aim is to pass the expected output of B to function A. I am using RSpec. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've attempted to write some classes and test cases for what it seems like you want to test.  The key here is to use `allow` to stub out the return value for a method.

Just note here that I've changed the methods in your class to be class methods to fit what seems to be your test case, but you can obviously change them back to instance methods to fit your purpose.  Also, accepted Ruby style is to have lowercase method names.

```
class ClassName
  def self.B
    # returns something that we're going to stub out
  end
end

class TestClass
  def self.A
    # do something
    output = ClassName.B
    # do something with output
    # eg in this case, add a value to it
    output << 2
  end
end

describe TestClass do
  describe '.A' do
    before do
      allow(ClassName).to receive(:B).and_return([0, 1])
    end

    it 'does something with output' do
      expect(described_class.A).to eq([0, 1, 2])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using `ClassName.stub(:B).and_return([0, 1]) ` instead of allow

Answer (score 2):

With RSpec you can do:

```
allow(ClassName).to receive(:B).and_return([1,2,3,4,5])
```

After this you can call B function and it will return [1,2,3,4,5]

You can find more info at RSpec documentation: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value

Answer (score 0):

There's ways as mentioned in other posts but I'll give you another: you might want to make that dependency explicit.

Here's how it could look like:

```
# test_class.rb
class TestClass
  # The default will be automatically setup to be an object of type ClassName
  def initialize(some_collaborator: ClassName.new)
    self.some_collaborator = some_collaborator # Some people will probably also insert some guard (to make sure it responds to `b`
  end

  def a
    # your code calling `some_collaborator.b`
  end

  private
  attr_accessor :some_collaborator
end

# test_class_spec.rb

describe TestClass do
  let(:stub_b) { stub("Some instance of ClassName", b: [...] }
  subject { TestClass.new(some_collaborator: stub_b) }

  it "whatever" do
    expect(subject.a).to ...
  end
end
```

The default collaborator should be a sensible default (and if you can't instantiate it there's ways to encapsulate it anyways). Not only it will be easier to read, but it will be easier to maintain.